# How to pass a specific instance variable into method in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am looking to pass a specific instance variable to a method instead of simply using 'self' which doesn't distinguish which variable I want to apply to the method. I know I can use self.printer() however this doesn't solve my issue of how to apply a single variable.

I am new to classes, so would appreciate any advice on how to approach this.

Simplified example:

```
class studentsObject:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.name0 = 'Nick'
        self.name1 = 'Ben'
    
    def printer(name):
        print('Student name:',name)
        
    def runAll(self):
        print(printer(self.name0)) # I would like to pass ONLY name0 to printer method
        print(printer(self.name1)) # I would like to pass ONLY name1 to printer method

students = studentsObject()
students.runAll()
```

Output:

```
NameError: name 'printer' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may need to call printer with self as it is within the same class, you also need to define self in method printer

```
class studentsObject:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.name0 = 'Nick'
        self.name1 = 'Ben'
    
    def printer(self,name):
        print('Student name:',name)
        
    def runAll(self):
        print(self.printer(self.name0)) # I would like to pass ONLY name0 to printer method
        print(self.printer(self.name1)) # I would like to pass ONLY name1 to printer method

students = studentsObject()
students.runAll()
```